# How to convert word in string array using System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode

Tags: c#, arrays

How to convert word in string array using System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode as 
well also remove it-> `"!!*!!"`

```
var array= new string []
               {"windows!!1!!","dual+sim!!3!!","32+gb!!2!!","Intel+i5!!2!!","red%2fblue"};
```

Output array

```
var Output-array= new string []
                   {"windows","dual sim","32 gb","Intel i5","red/blue"}
```

How can do like this in single line of code in C#

Comment: Not same buddy both are different

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's `HttpUtility.UrlDecode`

```
string[] array = new string[] { "windows!!1!!", "dual+sim!!3!!", "32+gb!!2!!", "Intel+i5!!2!!", "red%2fblue" };
string[] result = array.Select(x => System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlDecode(System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(x, @"!!.*!!", "")).Replace("+", " ")).ToArray();
```

Comment: Thanks :)  Replace(x, @"!!.*!!", "") it's vary help me when !!123!!

Comment: string[] result = array.Select(x => System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlDecode(System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(x, @"!!.*!!", "")).ToArray();

Comment: It's work and return "dual sim"  refer http://rextester.com/live/RNAQ48012